# How can i assign the access token to the accessToken property in the constructor

Tags: node.js, express

I need help in assigning the accessToken property in MyApi class. it seems that the accessToken is not being assigned properly in my constructor. I want to store the access token in the accessToken property so that i use it in the other methods. unfortunately its not being stored properly.

If i place the statement for assigning outside of the request object, the accessToken property is being assigned and i can access it from other methids using this.accessToken. the access token comes in through the request's callback where i extract it from the body. the problem is that it is not being stored properly into the accessToken property.

```
var request = require("request");

class MyApi {
  constructor() {
    request({ url: "URL", headers: { Authorization: "Basic KEY" } }, function(
      error,
      response,
      body
    ) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        // this console log statement logs the access token
        console.log(`Access Token : ${JSON.parse(body).access_token}`);

        // i try to set it into the accessToken property
        this.accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;

        // This statement logs undefined, meaning my accessToken property is not beinga ssiged successfully
        console.log(`Access Token Two: ${this.accessToken}`);
      }
    });
  }

  newRequest(callback) {
    request(
      {
        // Also if i try to use the accessToken property here, the request returns an error that the access token is invalid
        method: "POST",
        url: "URL",
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.accessToken },
        json: { key: "value", key: "value" }
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          callback(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
      }
    );
  }
}

module.exports = MyApi;
```

I want to use the access token in the other methods like the newRequest method to make more requests. someone help i'll appreciate

Addition:
Simplified version:

```
function request(f) {
    f("Token");
}

class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        request(function(t) {
            this.token = t;
        }); //.bind(this));
    }
    getToken() {
        return this.token;
    }
}

const q = new MyClass();
console.log(q.getToken());
```

UPD: Try to run simplified version and then check comment.

Comment: Can you simplify your code as much, as it possible without loosing important things. Maybe, you will find answer during such simplification. At least you'll be able to use proper words for question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions - here is explanation why it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use arrow functions, the problem will be solved. As you are using function, **this** refers to function reference, not class object reference

```
var request = require('request');

class MyApi {
  constructor() {
    request({
        url: "URL",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Basic KEY"
        }
      },
      (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
        } else {
          // this console log statement logs the access token
          console.log(`Access Token : ${JSON.parse(body).access_token}`)

          // i try to set it into the accessToken property
          this.accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token

          // This statement logs undefined, meaning my accessToken property is not beinga ssiged successfully
          console.log(`Access Token Two: ${this.accessToken}`)
        }
      }
    )
  }

  newRequest(callback) {
    request({
        // now it will work
        method: 'POST',
        url: "URL",
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.accessToken
        },
        json: {
          "key": "value",
          "key": "value"
        }
      },
      (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          ;
          callback(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
      }
    )
  }

}

module.exports = MyApi
```

Refer [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/) for a good explanation about **this**